# I have an error in server session and can't resolve it

Tags: php, server

when i click logout and page return to login again this line is be in display :

```
Warning: session_start(): open(C:\xampp8\tmp\sess_16k7kmv1kt181nv4eq17idhirg, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in C:\xampp8\htdocs\example.com\crm\init.php on line 8

Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: C:\xampp8\tmp) in C:\xampp8\htdocs\example.com\crm\init.php on line 8
```

---

### logout page >>>>>>

```
<?php
include "init.php" ; //include init
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: /');
exit();
?>
```

---

### init page >>>

```
<?php
//======================================================================================
//============================== session AND DB DASHBORD ===============================
//======================================================================================
//connect to database 
include "db.php";
//session start
session_start();
```

Comment: Check your browser cookies. You might have deleted the session, but left it in the browser. `session_start()` tries to resume the session from the cookie, but you deleted it on the server side.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you must use session_regenerate_id() before of session_start();

for more information read this link:
[session_destroy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Comment: where i can add it ? before session or after session or after session_destroy()